# Exact meaning of Function literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, literals, function-literal

In JavaScript there are both Object literals and function literals.

Object literal:

```
myObject = {myprop:"myValue"}
```

Function literal:

```
myFunction = function() {
   alert("hello world");
}
```

What is the significance of the word literal?  Can we say Java has method literals?

```
public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("are my literal");
}
```

Comment: You also have string/null/boolean/regexp/numerical/array literal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function literal is just an expression that defines an unnamed function.

The syntax for a function literal is much like that of the function statement, except that it is used as an expression rather than as a statement and no function name is required.

So When you give the method name then it can't be a method literal.

Comment: If functions were not literal in JavaScript they would always have to have a name.  In Java methods are not "literal" because they always have a name. They can never be defined on the fly, pass around or passed into method.

Answer (score 10):

The biggest difference is how/when it is parsed and used.
Take your exemple,

```
myFunction = function() {
   alert("hello world");
}
```

You can only run `myFunction()` after the code got to there, since you declare a variable with an anonymous function.

If you use the other way,

```
function myFunction(){
   alert("hello world");
}
```

This function is declared **at compile time** and can be used anytime in the scope.

Please refer to [this question also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

Answer (score 8):

Don't compare JavaScript with Java, they have about as much in common as a bear and a whale. Java is an object oriented programming language, whereas JavaScript is a functional programming language.

With a functional language comes the notion of functions as first class objects: functions can be assigned to variables, can be passed as arguments as they can be the return value of other functions.

An object literal is an object you create on-the-fly and in-line. Same applies for a function literal. But the example you're giving is actually similar to a regular function declaration:

```
function foo()
{
    alert('bar');
}
```

Is moved to the top of the scope, where it is *converted* to:

```
var foo = function()
{
    alert('bar');
};
```

Makes sense, when functions can be passed as arguments/return values:

```
var processed = (function(someFunc)//<-- argument name
{
    return function()
    {
        alert('I\'ll call some function in 2 seconds, get ready');
        setTimeout(someFunc,2000);//<-- passes a reference to foo, as an argument to setTimeout
    }
})(foo);//pass reference to function object foo here
```

This is only the beginning of all sorts of things you can do with JS, provided you stop treating it as a subset of Java....

Answer (score 8):

Add-on:

A function literal in JavaScript is a synonym for a function expression.

Parallel to function expressions, function literals can have an optional identifier (name).

So if we say function expressions / function literals, it includes function expressions / function literals without an identifier (also called anonymous functions), but also function expressions / function literals with an identifier. Even if in a lot of books function expression / function literal is used as a synonym for function expression / function literal without an identifier (anonymous functions).

> ### Function Literal
>
> Function objects are created with function literals:
>
> // Create a variable called add and store a function // in it that
>   adds two numbers.

```
> var add = function (a, b) {
>     return a + b; };
```

> A function literal has four parts.
>
> The first part is the reserved word function.
>
> The optional second part is the function's name. The function can use
>   its name to call itself recursively. The name can also be used by
>   debuggers and development tools to identify the function. If a
>   function is not given a name, as shown in the previous example, it is
>   said to be anonymous.
>
> The third part is the set of parameters of the function, wrapped in
>   parentheses. Within the parentheses is a set of zero or more parameter
>   names, separated by commas. These names will be defined as variables
>   in the function. Unlike ordinary variables, instead of being
>   initialized to undefined, they will be initialized to the arguments
>   supplied when the function is invoked.
>
> The fourth part is a set of statements wrapped in curly braces. These
>   statements are the body of the function. They are executed when the
>   function is invoked.
>
> A function literal can appear anywhere that an expression can
>   appear...
>
> source: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9780596517748/ch04s02.html) - Douglas Crockford

That means:

```
myFunction = function () {
   alert("hello world");
};
```

is a function expression / function literal, but also:

```
myFunction = function myFunction() {
   alert("hello world");
};
```

is a function expression / function literal.

Answer (score 1):

No official definition found in ECMA-262.

But according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29) and many other PLs I've learnt, **literals are expressions of values**.

That means:

```
function() {alert("hello world")}
```

is a literal, while:

```
function hello_world() {alert("hello world")}
```

is not. Because the latter expresses not only a value, but a **reference**.

I upvoted vsenol's answer, but now I think it is wrong.

Comment: hey, sry but I would prefer according to other resources than wiki.

Comment: @vsenol tell me if you have more trustworthy general or programming sources than wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

A `function literal` is not a `function`, but is what denotes a value of `function`.

For an assembly language programmer, it's something like a `block of code` that's stored in the `.text` area of memory.

Then people would want to ask what a `function` really is.

A `function` is actually a pointer or a reference to a value of function represented by a `function literal` as in any programming language.

---

For example,

```
public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("are my literal");
}
```

If we had `myMethod` which is a method,

```
{
    System.out.println("are my literal");
}
```

then this would be the method literal, which Java does not support.