# Function Literal vs Function Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Are function literals and function expressions the same thing, or is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, they're two different terms for the same concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: See also [Exact meaning of Function literal in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12314905/1048572) and [Difference between “anonymous function” and “function literal” in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5857459/1048572)

Comment: @AymanElTemsahi No, not of that one.

Answer (score 1):

As answered on topic [Exact meaning of Function literal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314905/exact-meaning-of-function-literal-in-javascript): *"A function literal **is** just **an expression** that defines an unnamed function."*

[Description of "function expression" on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) about function name says, that it *"Can be omitted, in which case the function is anonymous."*. (`unnamed function === anonymous function`)

Another example of anonymous function notation is *"arrow function expression"* in ES6

```
var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; };
```

This does **the same thing** as:

```
var func = function (x, y) { return x + y; };
```

and (almost) the same thing as:

```
function func(x, y) { return x + y; };
```

For more in-deph explanation read: [Difference between “anonymous function” and “function literal” in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5857498/1729641)

---

#### TL;DR:

Function Literal is kind of function expression.